# grep statement in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am using a for loop to connect to a list of servers and perform some simple commands. If the server is not accessible then stderr is written to a file. I then grep that file for the server name. It seems relatively simple and for some reason it isn't working. For troubleshooting purposes I have narrowed my server list to two servers and only run simple commands.

```
for i in $(cat serverlist)
do
    nexec -i $i hostname 2>>errorlog.txt
    if grep -q $i errorlog.txt; then echo "error accessing" $i
    else echo "was able to connect to" $i
    fi
done
```

So in the serverlist I have defined two incorrect hosts for troubleshooting purposes. Nexec tries to connect to each and perform the hostname command. If it is unable to connect an error message is printed to errorlog.txt

e.g., 
nexec: Error accessing host test1

Since both servers are incorrectly specified I am not able to connect to either. Again for troubleshooting purposes.

When grep runs the first time against $i which is the first server in the list it doen't find any matches in error.txt. However, it should. If I cat the results instead of grepping it is there.

I am actually doing this in bladelogic so the rules are a  bit different. It should still work.

Comment: Does it work for the second server in the list?

Comment: BTW, think about what happens if you have server101 and then server1: `grep server1` will succeed even if server1 failed and only server101 was a success.

Comment: BTW, do you need to read nexec's stderr at all? Are you **sure** it doesn't correctly represent whether an error occurred in its exit status?

Comment: BTW, `set -x` is your friend. Run `bash -x yourscript`, and it'll print all commands before they run, so you can easily figure out where unexpected behavior is first taking place.

Answer (score 1):

```
while read -r i <&3; do
    nexec -i "$i" hostname 2>>"errorlog.$i.txt" || {
      echo "nexec for $i exited with status $?" >&2
      continue
    }
    # check for case where it claimed success but actually failed
    # if nexec is written correctly, you don't need any of this logic
    # ...and can completely remove the rest of the loop.
    if grep -q -e "$i" "errorlog.$i.txt"; then
      echo "error accessing $i" >&2
    else
      echo "was able to connect to $i" >&2
    fi
done 3<serverlist

# and combine all the individual logs into one file:
cat errorlog.*.txt >errorlog.txt && rm -f -- errorlog.*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with nexec, but I imagine something like this is what you are looking for

```
for i in $(cat serverlist)
do
    if [ ! "$(nexec -i $i hostname)" ]
        then echo "error accessing" $i
      else echo "was able to connect to" $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: Since he's redirecting to `errorlog.txt` in append mode, I think he wants a permanent record of all the errors in that file.

Comment: `for x in $(cat foo)`, by the way, is horrible practice. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls (where it's covered by entry #1), and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for the better practice.

Comment: Also, quote your expansions: `nexec -i "$i"`

Comment: ...and the "error accessing" doesn't need to be inside quotes (for the echo command), but the `$i` does (to prevent string-splitting and glob expansion). Though it'd be best practice to put it all in quotes: `echo "error accessing $i"`.

Comment: ...see entry #14 on the pitfalls page to understand why quotes matter for echo.

Comment: Also, you're checking whether nexec has any output or not, which is an entirely different thing for checking for the server name inside its output.